# Reclassifying rasterstack in R?

Tags: r, reclassify, rasterstack

I have a very large raster stack of 6253 raster layers and I want to reclassify it. 
For the reclass, I have tried the following but with no success:

```
my_rules <- c(-0.500, -0.251, 1,  -0.251, -0.101, 2,  -0.101,0.99,3, 0.99,0.269,4, 0.269,0.439,5, 0.439,0.659,6, 0.659,1.300,7, 1.300,2,NA)
reclmat <- matrix(my_rules, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
my_stack<- reclassify(my_stack, reclmat,right=FALSE)

Error in .local(x, rcl, ...) : all(rcl[, 2] >= rcl[, 1]) is not TRUE
```

Is this the wrong way to approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reclassification matrix isn't right - I suspect the `0.990` on rows 3 and 4 should be `0.099` - as it is the rows make up overlapping classes so the function throws an error:

```
> reclmat
       [,1]   [,2] [,3]
[1,] -0.500 -0.251    1
[2,] -0.251 -0.101    2
[3,] -0.101  0.990    3
[4,]  0.990  0.269    4
[5,]  0.269  0.439    5
[6,]  0.439  0.659    6
[7,]  0.659  1.300    7
[8,]  1.300  2.000   NA
```

Its nothing to do with the size of the stack - you should always test things first on small examples. I duplicated your error with:

```
> r = raster()
> r[] = runif(ncell(r),-0.5,2)
> reclassify(r,reclmat)
Error: all(rcl[, 2] >= rcl[, 1]) is not TRUE
```

Change the `0.990` to `0.099` and it works:

```
> my_rules <- c(-0.500, -0.251, 1,  -0.251, -0.101, 2,  -0.101,0.099,3, 0.099,0.269,4, 0.269,0.439,5, 0.439,0.659,6, 0.659,1.300,7, 1.300,2,NA)
> reclmat <- matrix(my_rules, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
> reclassify(r,reclmat)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 180, 360, 64800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
```

Comment: Such a stupid mistake from me. Thank you for the notice @Spacedman!